# Extract file name from a file path starting with the given string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a given path. For eg., it looks like C:\documents. I have extracted this path name to a cell in Excel. Say, I have 5 files inside it. I want to extract the name of the file starting with "S".

Is there a way to implement this without using VBA?

Can somebody help me, please... TIA.

Comment: Sorry. That's not possible without VBA or an Add-In.

Comment: You want Excel to scan the folder with given path and show the files files matching the mask `S*.*`? No. There is no a worksheet function which get folder content.

Comment: In the folder path there are 5 files. Only one file starts with alphabet "S". I want to retrieve that file name to a cell. Since, if I do version control, everytime, I have to go back and change the file name. I want to automate it in a parsimonious way.

Comment: I would settle for a way that works (i.e. VBA)

Comment: Without Macro(VBA) it's difficult to get File/Files from any folder. Needless to say about File manager !!